# Query show result from relations where one of the value is 0

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with the following structure:

fornecido

```
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+
| codmaterial | idfornecedor | idmodelo | preco  |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     8978998 |            0 |      234 | 2.00   |
|     8978998 |          718 |        0 | 22.00  |
|     8978998 |          578 |      201 | 222.00 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

fornecedor

```
+--------------+---------------------------+---------+
| idfornecedor |           nome            | contact |
+--------------+---------------------------+---------+
|          578 | ACAR-IMPORT.EXPORT.LD.    | NULL    |
|          580 | ACCESS OFFICE VB          | NULL    |
|          581 | ACCIOP-CONST.OBR.PUB.,LD. | NULL    |
|          582 | ACCUSONIC TECHNOLOGIES    | NULL    |
|          583 | ACE NAVILECTRA TOME       | NULL    |
|          584 | ACE-ART.CIRURG.EUROPA,LD. | NULL    |
|          718 | ADIHOTEL-MAQ.EQUIP.HOT.LD | NULL    |
+--------------+---------------------------+---------+
```

modelo

```
+----------+-----------------+
| idmodelo |      nome       |
+----------+-----------------+
|      224 | 24TDMEJ50       |
|      140 | 259118          |
|      201 | 122AVP          |
|      234 | 1YMB531002M0005 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

I want to show the result with the names of fornecedor and modelo instead of ids.

```
SELECT
  fornecedor.nome, modelo.nome, preco
FROM
  fornecido, fornecedor, modelo
WHERE
  fornecido.codmaterial=8978998 AND condition
```

each condition that I've tried or result in all possible combinations or the only one that has both fornecedor and modelo :s

I pretend something like:

```
null, 1YMB531002M0005, 2.00
ADIHOTEL-MAQ.EQUIP.HOT.LD, null, 22.00
ACAR-IMPORT.EXPORT.LD., 122AVP, 222.00
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
fn.nome as FNOME, m.nome as MNOME, f.preco
FROM  fornecido f left join fornecedor fn 
on f.idfornecedor = fn.idfornecedor 
left join modelo m on f.idmodelo =m.idmodelo 
WHERE f.codmaterial=8978998
```

Check SQlFiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/251cc/5/0

For Reference :

http://placeisimportant.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/sql-joins-vis-rep-1.png
http://placeisimportant.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/sql-joins-vis-rep-2.png

Answer (score 2):

First, I like to structure my queries so I can see the relationships between the tables.  Next, you are looking specifically where either one (or maybe both) values have a zero value for one of the columns, but obviously do not want to hard-code a specific entry.

```
SELECT
      fn.nome, 
      m.nome, 
      f.preco
   FROM  
      fornecido f 
         LEFT JOIN fornecedor fn 
            on f.idfornecedor = fn.idfornecedor
         LEFT JOIN modelo m 
            on f.idmodelo = m.idmodelo 
   WHERE 
      f.codmaterial = 8978998
      AND (   f.idfornecedor = 0
           OR f.idmodelo = 0)
```

In this case, you probably need to use LEFT JOIN since the corresponding table would not have a record with an ID of 0 to join to, and using an INNER JOIN implies it MUST exist in the joined table.  LEFT JOIN allows the "fornecido" table to still show records regardless of a match into the other LEFT JOINed tables.

The WHERE clause is what is checking for = 0  (or you could check for NULL of the "other" tables).